# Add conditional text outpuT to cardprofile

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, bs4dash

I am using a `cardProfile` from `bs4Dash` library to show the current user in my `Shiny` app.

The cardProfile looks like this in the `ui` part:

```
   cardProfile(
     src = "logo.png",
     title = 'SHOW HERE THE USERNAME'
     subtitle = "Administrator",
     cardProfileItemList(
       bordered = TRUE,
       cardProfileItem(
         title = "Email",
         description = 'SHOW HERE THE EMAIL'
       )
     )
```

What should I use in the title and description to show a name and email depending on an input?

I have tried with a `textOutput`:

```
title = textOutput('title')

description = textOutput('email')
```

And a reactive in the `server` part with no result:

```
reactive({
  USER <- input$user
  output$title<- USER 
  output$email<- usuarios$email[usuarios$usuario == USER ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your card server-side in a renderUI(), and then display it in the UI with a UIOuptut().

Almost everytime you need to display in the UI something that is reactive, you must code it server-side or use an updateInput function when it exists.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

df_email <- data.frame(user = "toto",
                       email = "toto@toto.com")

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(,
                     header = dashboardHeader(),
                     sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
                     body = dashboardBody(
                       bs4Card(
                         uiOutput("card_user")
                       )
                     ),
                     title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) { 

    # USER <- reactive(input$user) #uncomment
    USER <- reactive("toto") #comment
    
    output$card_user <- renderUI({
      cardProfile(
        # src = "logo.png",
        title = 'SHOW HERE THE USERNAME',
        subtitle = "Administrator",
        cardProfileItem(
          title = USER(),
          description = df_email$email[df_email$user == USER()] #replace with your own data
          
        )
      )
    })
    }
)
```